# Length of data to hash for PGP

Tags: hash, implementation, pgp, dsa

I have finally managed to verify some simple PGP signed message blocks. However, I discovered that for some reason, my implementation limits me to verifying data that is 9-16 bytes long. no less. no more.

is there some instruction somewhere ([RFC4880](http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc4880.pdf) or elsewhere) that specifies how to deal with plaintext data of any length? maybe there is some sort of padding i missed? pkcs1?

I am pretty sure i formatted the data to hash properly, since the instructions in RFC 4880 sec 5.2.4 say for text documents, just replace all `\n` with `\r\n` and add a trailer. since my test values were single lines of data, nothing had to be replaced

all of these values are in base 10 unless otherwise noted:

```
// DSA public key values
p = 175466718616740411615640156350265486163809613514213656685227237159351776260193236923030228927905671867677337184318134702903960237546408302010360724274436019639502405323187799029742776686067449287558904042137172927936686590837020160292525250748155580652384740664931255981772117478967314777932252547256795892071
q = 809260232002608708872165272150356204306578772713
g = 127751900783328740354741342100721884490035793278553520238434722215554870393020469115393573782393994875216405838455564598493958342322790638050051759023658096740912555025710033120777570527002197424160086000659457154926758682221072408093235236853997248304424303705425567765059722098677806247252106481642577996274
y = 172935968966072909036304664996424500241381878537444332146572958203083745609400290814117451480512268901233962890933482206538294509037615827035398352528065134903071886710296983781453184598843331365336270501467458073523376152406987560592548479865116940266729198119357206749848310472131186772143408998928864559411
```

not working:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1

abcd
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: BCPG v1.39

iFsEARECABsFAk/tB28UHGFiYyA8bWFrY21AYWFhLmNvbT4ACgkQMFIlRc933Ya2
RwCfdMyI08Iz0rDXVHOPlGA3s5Y9j/8An2He7+hHjWfGJNoOJT7gAxqJaoLo
=I2rT
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

data hashed (in hex): 6162636404011102001b05024fed076f141c616263203c6d616b636d406161612e636f6d3e04ff00000021

r = 666804200764671083282351405489424949903645052927
s = 558743769080942454889260816818443017172325925608

w =  702955297882281869313155599553522395227576660460 // s^-1 mod q
u1 = 190417717173929082607343542521304347388874234334
u2 = 306786785479358548892951170619047936651163362761
v = g^u1 * y^u2 % p % q = 737052148656331043521702886300418501784667890334

v != r
```

working:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1

0123456789abcdef
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: BCPG v1.39

iFsEARECABsFAk/tCE0UHGFiYyA8bWFrY21AYWFhLmNvbT4ACgkQMFIlRc933YYG
IQCfercgPsXFnah6otgQdEMbv9OeCgIAnRIyOLirbqSlBugBT6Ex/Adz4+7L
=bzab
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

data hashed (in hex): 3031323334353637383961626364656604011102001b05024fed084d141c616263203c6d616b636d406161612e636f6d3e04ff00000021

r = 700580719365380086754774917458461236187098909186
s = 103881812262595813943381509986903840453887782603

w = 178510125628083028184051840492924307896586330444 // s^-1 mod q
u1 = 78831508775508876446567239486098677466912246622
u2 = 572875590470993668032596348682349224460207395691
v = g^u1 * y^u2 % p % q = 700580719365380086754774917458461236187098909186

v == r
```

what data did i not include in the hash / what did i do wrong?

Anybody?

Comment: cross posted and answered on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256853/length-of-data-to-hash-for-pgp

Comment: it did take over a week to get an answer. i had hoped to get an answer sooner, by posting in multiple places. anyways, should i delete this, or leave it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the original answer at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11402200/416646)

> Haven't got enough time to look up the details, but I would guess that you're applying (or not applying) padding correctly. That would cause the right result to come up for some input lengths, but not for others.
>
> I guess I'll look into this more, but I wanted to get something in under the bounty wire :)
>
> **Edit**: Ok, found an error. Not sure why you're getting it, but if it's fixed, then the right answer comes out. In your not-working example, you calculate `w` (s^-1 mod q) as
>
> ```
>  w =  702955297882281869313155599553522395227576660460 // s^-1 mod q
> ```
>
> but I get
>
> ```
>  w =  702955297882281869313155599553522395227576660458
> ```
>
> off by 2! Really, really close values though. And it can be shown that mine is right:
>
> ```
> s * your_w mod q = 308227306159276200906356361486529830038073078504
>
> s * my_w mod q = 1
> ```
>
> If you plug in this w value, you then get
>
> ```
> u1 = 536931432138658080437983667536052790245747416035
>   u2 = 591698847955233800072578903940910445457030802333
>   v = (g^u1 * y^u2) % p % q = 666804200764671083282351405489424949903645052927
>   r == v
> ```
>
> Hope that helps.